# How can I request from pyDrive a csv conversion to google spreadsheet that handles correctly the decimal separator mark?

Tags: python, csv, locale, pydrive

I am using python to upload a csv file to Google Drive. The csv file uses decimal point as the decimal separator mark, but when converted to google spreadsheet misconversions come up:

Example: a decimal number 1.10 is taken as text (aceptable), but sometimes is converted to a date string, which renders the number unreadable.

This is the code:

```
metadata = {'title' : cloud_filename, 
            'parents':  [{"kind": "drive#fileLink","id": parent_id}]}
file1 = drive.CreateFile(metadata)
file1.SetContentFile(local_filepath)
file1.Upload({'convert':True})  # Upload the file.
```

[According to this thread in Google Drive Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Wnj4MUsoDLs), the language setting of the spreadsheet document or the language of the Drive interface will be responsible for the conversion using decimal point or decimal comma.

- **Can the interface language of Google Drive be requested?** (So I can prepare the csv file accordingly)
- **Can the language of my uploaded file be set using metadata?** (So it can match the language of the interface)
- **May you have another way of getting csv file correctly converted into google spreadsheet?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the interface language of Google Drive be requested?

yes, you can get the user information using

```
info = drive.auth.service.about().get().execute()
```

Then the language will be given by `info['languageCode']`. The style will be `en_US` for example.

From `info` you can get the name, email, total storage available, etc.

```
info['name']
info['user']['emailAddress']
info['quotaBytesUsed']
```